# jQuery recall a function to play the next audio file

Tags: jquery, audio, each, repeat

I found a function to play an audio file (onclick) and she works fine

I want to use this function to play the next audio file when the current is ended
So I recall the function inside onended, the next audio file is played but it freezes and repeats itself to infinity without passing to the next file

```
var thissound = new Audio();
var currentKey;

function EvalSound(key)
{
    if (currentKey !== key)
        thissound.src = "media/audio/chapters/" + chapternum + "/" + key + ".mp3";
        currentKey = key;

    if (thissound.paused)
    {
        thissound.play();
    }
    else
    {
        thissound.pause();
        thissound.currentTime = 0;
        currentPlayer = thissound;
    }
 }
$(".audio").click(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var parentid = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');     
    var nextfile = parseInt(parentid)  + 1; 

    EvalSound(parentid);

    thissound.onended = function()
    {
        EvalSound(nextfile);
        return false;
    }; 
});
```

HTML (for example)

```
<li class="liste" id="1">
    <p><img class="audio" src="images/default/buttons/play.png" alt="Play" title="Play" /></p>
    <p>some text</p>
</li>
<li class="liste" id="2">
    <p><img class="audio" src="images/default/buttons/play.png" alt="Play" title="Play" /></p>
    <p>some text</p>
</li>
...
...
```

Thanks you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it
So, I put "thissound.onended = function()" inside the function

```
thissound.onended = function()
{
    var nextfile = parseInt(key)  + 1;
    if($("#" + nextfile).length)
    {
        $(window).scrollTop($('#' + nextfile).offset().top);
        EvalSound(nextfile);
    }
};
```